# "deny all" for all files in a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My server is getting hit hard by bots, etc., looking for various files in `/cgi-bin/`, like `search.cgi, YaBB.pl, gitweb.perl, perl, gitweb.pl, htsearch,` and on and on.

I want to deny all access (send a 403 Forbidden header) for all possible file names and extensions in `/cgi-bin`/ . (This is a shared server, so I only have access to .htaccess, not `vhosts` or `httpd`).

In an .htaccess in `cgi-bin` I've tried

```
deny from all
```

as well as

```
<FilesMatch "\.cgi?$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

for just `.cgi` extensions, with no luck for either.

How can I deny access for everything in `/cgi-bin/`?

Do I need to list all file names and extensions in a `<FilesMatch` directive?

Comment: Why? If the file doesn't exist they will get a 404 and it will be totally harmless. I don't see any benefit from using a different error code.

Comment: I'm trying to keep my 404 log a bit cleaner so I can spot valid 404's better.

Comment: Then it sounds like a much better idea to simply modify the script you use to find the 404s in the log such that it will ignore URL prefixes you know not to be interesting.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm stuck with AWSTATs, which is a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the ip or user-agent which is cause of high traffic?

```
<Directory /cgi-bin>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</Directory>
```

Alt,

```
RewriteRule   "cgi(.*)"   "go_away"
```

Comment: Thanks, but they are all different IPs and agents, so that's a non-go. And the `<directory` rule above shows a 403 for `/cgi-bin/` but not for `/cgi-bin/search.cgi`

Comment: Not sure if you have multiple vhosts, try adding `AllowOverride All`  `Option -ExeCGI` above `order deny,allow`

Comment: Still no luck; this is a shared server, so I only have access to .htaccess, not vhosts or httpd, and it seems to be limited access at that, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of way to achieve this :

1. **Using Directory (Apache 2.2 version):**

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   </Directory>
   ```
2. **Using rewrite condition:**

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin
   RewriteRule .* - [END,R=406]
   ```

you can change 406 by any code you want as 403 for forbiden, you can find here the list of status code : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

And you can even extend the rewrite condition to cover more bot:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule .* - [END,R=406]
```

thoose rules prevent from empty useragent, request starting by /cgi, limit method to GET/HEAD/POST, request not starting by /

3. **Using the more logical way:**

Just move or remove cgi-bin from your web folder if you don't use them.